# Fill mysql with dates for a period of time from php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a mysql table with the following columns:
Date, Km

I would like to make a number of rows with dates from eg. 2018-01-01 to 2018-02-20.

The column "Km" must contain the value 0.

How can I do this using PHP and mysql?

I can't make this work:

```
<?php
$DateQuery = "

CREATE PROCEDURE fill_calendar(start_date Date, end_date Date)
BEGIN
  DECLARE crt_date Date;
  SET crt_date=start_date;
  WHILE crt_date < end_date DO
    INSERT INTO run VALUES(crt_date);
    SET crt_date = ADDDATE(crt_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END

";

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query("CALL fill_calendar('2018-01-01', '2018-02-20')");
?>
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow we are not here to write your code for you, you need to provide us with some of your efforts/attempts, thanks.

Comment: Updated with the code I have but that does not work.

Comment: why does it have to be a stored procedure? and why are you still using mysql_query?

Comment: Do you change the DELIMITER, and execute the procedure, somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want a stored procedure for that. All you need is a single `INSERT` query, e.g.

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTimeImmutable('2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTimeImmutable('2018-02-20 23:59:59')
);

$values = implode(',', array_map(
    function(DateTimeInterface $dt) {
        return sprintf('(%s)', $dt->format('Y-m-d'));
    },
    iterator_to_array($period)
));

echo "INSERT INTO run VALUES $values";
```

This would print (some values omitted for brevity)

```
INSERT INTO run VALUES (2018-01-01),(2018-01-02),[…],(2018-02-20)
```

which you can then execute against the database with your db lib of choice.

Comment: You're right this is an easier way to accomplish it. Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me... (it does need a valid date range however)

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE fill_calendar(start_date Date, end_date Date)
BEGIN
  DECLARE crt_date Date;
  SET crt_date=start_date;
  WHILE crt_date < end_date DO
    INSERT INTO run VALUES(crt_date);
    SET crt_date = ADDDATE(crt_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END
$

-- Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

DELIMITER ;


CREATE TABLE run(crt_date DATE NOT NULL);

-- Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.14 sec)

CALL fill_calendar('2018-01-01', '2018-02-20');

-- Query OK, 1 row affected (0.52 sec)

SELECT * FROM run;
+------------+
| crt_date   |
+------------+
| 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-02 |
| 2018-01-03 |
| 2018-01-04 |
| 2018-01-05 |
| 2018-01-06 |
| 2018-01-07 |
| 2018-01-08 |
| 2018-01-09 |
| 2018-01-10 |
| 2018-01-11 |
| 2018-01-12 |
| 2018-01-13 |
| 2018-01-14 |
| 2018-01-15 |
| 2018-01-16 |
| 2018-01-17 |
| 2018-01-18 |
| 2018-01-19 |
| 2018-01-20 |
| 2018-01-21 |
| 2018-01-22 |
| 2018-01-23 |
| 2018-01-24 |
| 2018-01-25 |
| 2018-01-26 |
| 2018-01-27 |
| 2018-01-28 |
| 2018-01-29 |
| 2018-01-30 |
| 2018-01-31 |
| 2018-02-01 |
| 2018-02-02 |
| 2018-02-03 |
| 2018-02-04 |
| 2018-02-05 |
| 2018-02-06 |
| 2018-02-07 |
| 2018-02-08 |
| 2018-02-09 |
| 2018-02-10 |
| 2018-02-11 |
| 2018-02-12 |
| 2018-02-13 |
| 2018-02-14 |
| 2018-02-15 |
| 2018-02-16 |
| 2018-02-17 |
| 2018-02-18 |
| 2018-02-19 |
+------------+
50 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```